# Jekyll syntax highlighting with data variable

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm working on a Jekyll page that shows a list of items with their *markdownified-syntax highlighted* code. I've a data file with content like this

````
# myitems.yaml
id: 'someID'
updated: 'someDate'

items:
  - item:
    id: "0001"
    content: "
*This is italicized*, and so is _this_. 
**This is bold**, and so is __this__. & 
Use ***italics and bold together*** if you ___have to___. 
``` html 
<script>alert() some content</script> 
<p>paragraph</p>
 ```"
  - item:
    id: "0002"
    content: "some more content"
````

So the `items[].content` has markdown+some code to be syntax highlighted.

I'm accessing this data in my `items.html` with liquid as

```
<ul>
{% for item in site.data.myitems.items %}
    <li id="{{item.id}}">
        <div>{{ item.content | strip | markdownify}}</div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I'm using rouge syntax highlighting. The markdown is parsed properly to html but the html syntax highlighting is not working in the `items.html` part. Syntax highlighting works properly in post body but not in `{% include items.html %}`

The `items` output i get is: [image: output image]

```
<em>This is italicized</em>, and so is <em>this</em>. <strong>This is bold</strong>, and so is <strong>this</strong>. &amp; Use <strong><em>italics and bold together</em></strong> if you <strong><em>have to</em></strong>. <code class="highlighter-rouge">html &lt;script&gt;alert() some content&lt;/script&gt; &lt;p&gt;paragraph&lt;/p&gt;</code>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

solved by using the pipe instead of regular string quotes.

````
-item:
  id:"0001"
  content: |
  *This is italicized*, and so is _this_. 
  **This is bold**, and so is __this__. & 
  Use ***italics and bold together*** if you ___have to___. 
  ``` html 
  <script>alert() some content</script> 
  <p>paragraph</p>
  ```
````